# ArcGIS Add Join Attribute Table on ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I can Add Join Attribute Tables using two shape files by manual on ArcMap.
But I want to add join attribute tables using two shapre files on ModelBulder without ArcMap.
Can I do it ?

Please let me know some informations.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do it if you work with Feature Layer.

1. in the data management toolbox > Layers and table view > make
   Feature Layer (for feature classes) or make table View (for tables)
2. data management tools > Joins > add join with your layers as input.